# Dialing emergency numbers with no network available. How?

Tags: signal-processing, network

When the network is not available on my phone, it says "emergency calls only". It means that even if I'm in the middle of the desert, with no towers in the vicinity, I can dial the emergency number.

How can emergency calls get connected through, without any cellular signal available?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cellphone network coverage, and not physics.

Comment: Telecommunication is a part of physics. And this site was the closest bet, I could post on. I couldn't find a more appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Not finding a better site is *not* a reason to post something here. And if you don't ask about the physics *behind* telecommunication, it will almost always be off-topic as *engineering/not physics*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When your phone says that no network is available, it actually means that *your* network is not available. Fortunately though, mobile phones can make emergency calls on *any* network, and so if it finds another network then it can make emergency calls on that.

If *no* network is available whatsoever (e.g. out in the desert) then you *cannot* make emergency calls.

---

[As a side note: emergency service operators receive more calls on Christmas day than any other. The reason? Because people like to test their new mobile phones on Christmas day before they have a network setup, so they briefly dial 911 (or whatever).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misanthropy)

Comment: Just wondering, why is the link to the wikipedia page for misanthropy?

Comment: I am wondering too... -_-

Comment: because people are awful.

Comment: Note that this doesnt mean that when the phone offers you to do an emergency call, that then actually any other network is available, the button/link/icon is just there, in case.